# How do I determine the position of one vector relative to another?

Tags: unity, vector, kinect

I'm making a game for Kinect in Unity which tracks hand movements. I have the player's root position and the position of their fist stored as 3-dimensional vectors (`Vector3` in Unity), but they're both in world space.

**How can I determine the location of the player's fist relative to their root position?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Vector3 relativeFistPosition = globalFistPosition - globalRootPosition;` to get the fist position relative to the root. Use this new Vector3 for comparing different moves.